# How to run the custom animate.css grunt task from my grunt file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I would like to incorporate the custom grunt tasks declared in a bower dependency into my own grunt build file. The library in question is animate.css - https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

The associated grunt file is here: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

The author has created a custom task called `concat-anim` and allows you to declare which animations you wish to include in a build by customising `animate-config.json`. It's all documented on the github readme page for more information.

My project directory is typical:

```
bower_components/
  animate.css/
    Gruntfile.js
    animate-config.json
    ...
Gruntfile.js
bower.json
package.json
...
```

---

I would like to if possible, execute the `animate.css` `concat-anim` task from my own grunt file using my modified copy of the `animate-config.json`.

1. Is it possible to import the custom task into my project?
2. If so, how might I go about overriding the configuration json?